# How to replace http request parameter value

Tags: configuration, nginx

I'm using nginx to proxy requests from clients to JSON data provider backend. How i can replace one of the request parameters, if one exists, but doesn't satisfies regexp `^\d{1,2}$`?

Now i'm at this point:

```
    location / {
        if ( $arg_limit !~ "^\d{1,2}$" ) {
            rewrite         ^(.*)$  $1?limit=10 break;
        }

        proxy_pass  http://data_provider;
    }
```

It works, when `limit` argument aren't defined, but take place for double `limit` arguments, if one defined in the request.

Required behaviour:

```
# no limit arg, add one with default value
/path?key=1   →   /path?limit=10&key=1

# arg value satisfies regexp, don't rewrite
/path?key=1&limit=50   →   /path?key=1&limit=50

# arg value doesn't satisfies regexp, replace with default
/path?key=1&limit=5000   →   /path?limit=10&key=1
```

Arguments order doesn't matter, of course.

```
nginx/1.0.10
configure arguments: 
    --with-ipv6 --with-pcre --with-http_ssl_module 
    --with-http_addition_module --with-http_xslt_module 
    --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module 
    --with-http_secure_link_module
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this module:
https://github.com/chaoslawful/lua-nginx-module

You can modidy args,header, and other magic thing

OpenResty , a better way to use ngx_lua_module :
http://openresty.org/